# Change Datatype of Values in a Pandas SQL Insert Statement

Tags: sql, pandas, sqldatatypes, read-sql

Using Pandas `read_sql()` function to `INSERT` data into a SQL table called `table_1`. Pulling data from a primary database and writing to `table_1`.

```
# Creates the table

    read_sql(
        f"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_1} (id varchar, centroid varchar, date int, thresh bigint)

        """
    )
```

Using a loop to process multiple days and calling function_1.

```
date_format = "%Y%m%d"
dates_to_compute = pd.date_range(start='2022-09-01', end='2022-09-10', freq='D').strftime(date_format)

for date in dates_to_compute:
         print(f"Executing date {date}")
         query = f"""
              INSERT INTO {table_1}
              {function_1(id, centroid, date, thresh)}
         """
         read_sql(query)
```

Here is the error statement:

> DatabaseError:
> Insert query has mismatched column types:
> Table: [varchar, varchar, integer, bigint],
> Query: [bigint, varchar, double, double, array(varchar(9))]

My question is can I modify the `INSERT` statement to change the datatypes so that they match those of `table_1` that was created earlier.

Comment: **IF** the source data is appropriate, you can `cast` it to the correct data type.  The double columns may fail casting to integer.  Additionally, you have 4 columns in your table, but your error message shows you trying to insert 5.

Comment: I will look into `cast`. I noticed that also 4 vs. 5, but working on one issue at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Typically, you would only use `read_sql()` for select statements. You would use `DataFrame.to_sql()` to insert into a table. Why are you using `read_sql()` to insert to the table?

Comment: I am new to this particular function. But I am using existing code and having to modify for multiple dates. The best that I can say is that I am reading from another SQL database and not a pandas DF.